# Trigger different event on QTimer reset

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I am building a little program that shows traffic light images using QTimer. So i setup my timer and everything works good. But I cant figure out, how can I get the Robot Lights to ->show() and ->hide() each time the timer interval is reached. I can have this all wrong, im still learning so please advise.

mainwindow.h

```
 #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void timer();
    QTimer *mytimer;



private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int timerValue;

private slots:
    void showGreen();
    void showYellow();
    void showRed();
    void on_startButton_clicked();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   ui->green->setVisible(false);
    ui->yellow->setVisible(false);
     ui->red->setVisible(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timer(){
    ui->green->setVisible(true);
    mytimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mytimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showYellow()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue = (ui->spinBox->value())*1000);

}

void MainWindow::showYellow(){
    ui->yellow->setVisible(true);
    mytimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mytimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showRed()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}

void MainWindow::showRed(){
   ui->red->setVisible(true);
    mytimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mytimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showGreen));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}
void MainWindow::showGreen(){
    ui->green->setVisible(true);
    mytimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(mytimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showYellow()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}
void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    timer();
    ui->startButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```

I Also disable the Start button when clicked so the timer cannot run twice.

So On the main Window UI I basicly Have a Spinbox that takes the input of the user which is the time that I pass that to Qtimer, and then I have the 3 images with lights red green yellow that has to show and hide  in the intervals . So I created almost something like a manual loop. Qtimer starts and shows Green, then goes to ShowYellow Slot and then showRed slot, so now, its suppose to go to the Green slot and then to yellow, but it doesnt go to Green again.

Can someone tell me why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the comments:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ...
    mytimer = new QTimer(this); // create QTimer once
}

void MainWindow::timer() {
    timerValue = ui->spinBox->value() * 1000;

    showGreen(); // reuse showGreen()
}

void MainWindow::showYellow() {
    // this is how toggling can be done
    ui->yellow->setVisible(!ui->yellow->isVisible());

    mytimer->disconnect(); // disconnect before making a new connection
    connect(mytimer ,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showRed()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}

void MainWindow::showRed() {
    ui->red->setVisible(!ui->red->isVisible());

    mytimer->disconnect();
    connect(mytimer ,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showGreen()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}

void MainWindow::showGreen() {
    ui->green->setVisible(!ui->green->isVisible());

    mytimer->disconnect();
    connect(mytimer ,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showYellow()));
    mytimer->start(timerValue);
}
```

Comment: Im not really following what your saying.  Will this solve my problem of showing and Hiding the images? or is this just better practise of my program?

Comment: Having several timers calling same slot is not just a bad practice, it's a problem. @Wintermute showed how you can toggle image visibility.

Comment: I Fixed that problem by disabling the button when the user clicks on it. according to the assignment, the timer should not bee able to stop unless closed, so thats fine for now.   I still have a problem, would you mind leaving a comment on the new edit I made to the Question/Code

Comment: Read with the comments.

Comment: Wow Thanks so much. Didnt know I could create only one timer.  But now the program is skipping Yellow for some reason. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps most simply:

```
void MainWindow::showHide(){
    ui->green->setVisible(!ui->green->isVisible());
}
```

The `show()` and `hide()` member functions of `QWidget` are equivalent to `setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)`, respectively.

A problem you may run into later, if you press the start button more than once, is that you spawn a new interval timer every time, leading to quicker blinking with every press of the button. If this is not what you want to happen, you'll have to control the generation of new timers.